# Retrieve list values loaded in page_load

Tags: c#, list

I am populating a list in Page_Load that I want to access later to bind a ddl.

I have tried to get the values using this however the list seems to be empty.

```
foreach (var E in employeeDDL)
{
   Response.Write("Value " + E.ValueDDL);
}
```

List

```
public class EmployeeDDL
{
    private string valueDDL;
    private string textDDL;
    public EmployeeDDL(string valueDDL, string textDDL)
    {
        this.valueDDL = valueDDL;
        this.textDDL = textDDL;
    }

    public string ValueDDL
    {
        get { return valueDDL; }
        set { valueDDL = value; }
    }

    public string TextDDL
    {
        get { return textDDL; }
        set { textDDL = value; }
    }
}
```

Populate in Page Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<EmployeeDDL> EmployeeDDL = new List<EmployeeDDL>();
            using (MicrosoftDynamicsAXEntities db = new MicrosoftDynamicsAXEntities())
            {
                var employee = (from emp in db.Reports_EmplTable
                                where emp.CostCenter != "700"
                                && emp.VALIDTO > DbFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -30)
                                && emp.TimeTracking == "daStreetSmart"
                                orderby emp.FULLNAME
                                select new { emp.FULLNAME, emp.EMPLID } into x
                                select new { x.EMPLID, TextFieldValue = x.EMPLID + " - " + x.FULLNAME }
                ).ToList();
                foreach (var em in employee)
                {
                    EmployeeDDL.Add(new EmployeeDDL(em.EMPLID, em.TextFieldValue));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Need to retrieve later to bind ddl in the footer of a repeater.

```
protected void Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DropDownList ddlEmployees = AdvanceSummary.Controls[AdvanceSummary.Controls.Count - 1].FindControl("ddlEmployees") as DropDownList;
ddlEmployees.Visible = true;
ddlEmployees.DataValueField = "ValueDDL"; //need to use it here
ddlEmployees.DataTextField = "TextDDL"; //need to use it here
ddlEmployees.DataSource = employeeDDL; //need to use it here
ddlEmployees.DataBind();
}
```

I expect the ddl to load the employees retrieved from populating the list however the list is empty.

Comment: you are creating a new instance of List<EmployeeDDL> before accessing it, so it would be empty always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate lists: `EmployeeDDL` and `employeeDDLs`.  You are trying to use `employeeDDLs` as the data source for your dropdown:

```
ddlEmployees.DataSource = employeeDDLs;
```

But a few lines above that, you are creating the list but never filling it up:

```
List<EmployeeDDL> employeeDDLs = new List<EmployeeDDL>();
```

As far as we can tell from what you have shown us, you never again use the list `EmployeeDDL`.

Why are you creating `EmployeeDDL` in `Page_Load`?  Do you need it here?  If you are not going to use it until you populate the dropdown 'ddlEmployees', then just move all of the list creation and data access down to just above where 'ddlEmployees' is created and filled.

If, however, you DO need the list `EmployeeDDL` in multiple places, and you need to persists it across page callbacks, then you'll want to place the list into a ViewState variable.

Comment: Hi Casey, my goal was to only create it in Page_Load and then use it later so how would I place it into the ViewState variable to use later? Or should I use a session variable? I guess there is no way to do what I want without storing in a variable?

Comment: I wanted to create the list in page load so it doesn't reload on every postback. I also use the ddl in the footer of a repeater and could not access it to populate the ddl until the repeater loads. I do not know who downvoted this or why they did but it's bs.

Comment: The best practice is to create and populate your variables at the moment you are going to use them, and not before.  In this case, if you are not going to use the list in the Page_Load, then you really should not be creating and filling it up there.

Comment: I was trying to speed things up as well as void repopulating the list on post back. Is there another way to accomplish this as users are complaining about load time while the ddl is populating.

Comment: @DougFarrell, like I said.. if you want to load the data for the drop down list in the page-load method, that's fine!  But then you need to save that data into a ViewState variable so that it can be used later.

Comment: Casey, I marked your answer as the correct one however I added the list to a session variable instead of a ViewState variable.

Comment: Ok, understood. Just make sure you understand the difference between the two. Both have advantages and disadvantages.